# What happens if you disable System Firmware in Device Manager?

Tags: windows-10, firmware, device-manager

In Device Manager, there is the option to disable System Firmware. Just out of curiosity, what would happen if you tried to disable the System Firmware in Device Manager? Would it let you? What would the outcome be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Firmware is responsible for providing critical boot and runtime services to the system as a whole. Some computers may call if System Firmware.  I have Intel firmware (not BIOS) on my ThinkPad. It is not called System Firmware in my Device Manager.

Do not disable it as that may cause problems with starting (booting).

You may wish to update it. I can do that on my machine with a Lenovo App. Other manufacturers have their own apps.

Here is a decent description that may assist you.

https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/What-is-System-Firmware-in-Device-Manager/td-p/6022239

> There are two types of firmware that can be serviced via Windows:
> system firmware and device firmware. System firmware is responsible
> for providing critical boot and runtime services to the system as a
> whole, and device firmware is associated with a particular device
> integrated into a system.A firmware update is a software program that
> can be used to update the firmware in these devices.